Use Vite as remote app in Webpack 5 dynamic remotes container
I'm trying to migrate my remote app from Webpack 5 to Vite.js and I am stuck at loading dynamically remotes by the host that works with Webpack 5.
The remote app exposes an entry point file with Vite Plugin Federation. This is vite.config.js file:
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        federation({
            name: 'cdn',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
                './cdnApplication': './src/main.js'
            },
            shared: ['vue']
        })
    ],
    server: {
        port: 3002
    }
})

And this is my webpack.config.js file:
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'mfe_host_panel',
    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    remotes: {},
}),

Now my problem is here where dynamiclly loads the containers in the host app:
function loadComponent(scope, module) {
    return async () => {
        await __webpack_init_sharing__("default");
        const container = window[scope];

        await container.init(__webpack_share_scopes__.default); // the problem is here cause of container is undefined when the remote app is on vite.
        const factory = await window[scope].get(module);
        const Module = factory();
        return Module;
    };
}

How can I fix this issue and load my remote app?
Is there another approach to help me?
